# SDL2.0 with XCode 4.6

Tags: xcode, macos, opengl, sdl

I've managed to build SDL2.0 and I got my SDL2.framework folder built. Don't know if I placed it in the correct location on my system. I'm using XCode 4.6 with OS X 10.8. I placed it here `/System/Library/Frameworks`

When I start a new XCode project I choose Command Line Application. Select to add OpenGL.framework and then I try to add SDL2.framework but it doesn't appear on the search list. I then click on Add Other and manually select SDL2.framework located in `/System/Library/Frameworks`.  I then add some simple SDL code and try to build. I get this error then:

```
SDL.h file not found
```

I can see in my XCode project that the SDL2.framework is there and I can expand it o see that SDL.h exists and I can even open it.

What am I missing here?

Comment: How do you include sdl.h in your code?

Comment: #include "SDL.h".  Should it be different??

Comment: Check settings in your IDE where are include locations for your files.

Comment: Should the include location point to where the SDL2.framework is ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `#include <SDL.h>`? That's at least what I've been doing  and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I normally put my framework in /Library/Frameworks/ but it is up to you where you put it as long as you link it correctly.

If you have added it correctly to your project then it shouldn't cause an issue. You may want to add the Cocoa.framework as well depending on what you are doing.

The most portable way to include for SDL2 is:

```
#include "SDL.h"
```

You just need to ensure you have the additional include directories configured in either your IDE or makefile etc accordingly, so that the folder where SDL.h resides is listed.

Comment: The [SDL FAQ](http://wiki.libsdl.org/moin.fcg/FAQDevelopment#Do_I_.23include_.3CSDL.h.3E_or_.3CSDL.2BAC8-SDL.h.3E.3F) still says that you should include it like this: `#include "SDL.h"`. You then have to set your include path to something like `…/include/SDL2`.

Comment: It seems that depending of the platform, the path `SDL2/` is not created. For example, in MacOSX, the framework doesn't contain this intermediate directory. On other platforms it exists, a possible solution could be use only `#import "SDL.h"` and modify the header search paths when SDL2 directory is present.

Comment: thanks, i always assumed -framework meant you didn't have to set include paths manually but passing "-I /Library/Frameworks/SDL2/Headers" worked for me

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me when I put my SDL2 framework in /Library/Frameworks/, add the framework in build phases, and include header with #include <SDL2/SDL.h>